# Apache Camel and Anti Virus

Tags: apache-camel, antivirus

Hy there,

I'm currently writing a camel client, that integrates into our companies file transfer tool.
As our next feature, we want to be able to scan files, that are send via our software with some antivirus software.
For different reasons we decided to do this with our camel client.

After resarching a bit I could not find any article or project, that talks about camel and scanning files for viruses.

Does anyone have any experience with this topic or is there something planed for camel to have an component for this in the future?
I think as the first step having a clamav client as a component would be awesome.

Any thoughts?

Greets
Chris

Comment: If you can invoke your anti virus software from within Java, you can basically do the same in Camel. Either use a `.bean(...)` invocation or write your own component that internally performs that invocation. I'm not aware of any plans to introduce such things to Camel and I'm also not sure if a component is actually the right thing for such a job.

Comment: I think you should have files placed in a secure location where they are already scanned and ready to work with.

Comment: @Namphibian The problem is, that this won't work with our workflow (if I understand you correctly). 1. We start the route when there is a new file in the transfer software, that should be checked, 2. We give the file to the virus scanner and wait for the result, 3. We mark the file as ok or delete it on the transfer server (depending on the result). When I just put them in a folder, I never know, when the scanner is done and the transfer server will forever wait for my result